# MigraDoc Formatting

Tags: format, migradoc

I am completely new to PDF creation including MigraDoc. I have gotten this far, which is really close to what I want for now. My question is that the text string (myMessage) that I pass to the "bodyParagraph" is up to 100 lines long, which causes three pages to be created, which is good. However the first page's Top margin is slightly greater than the second and third pages. I have no idea of why...

Basically, I am trying to create every page the same. Same header, footer and the body to take the same space regardless of the number of lines in the "bodyParagraph" content. If I have taken the completely wrong approach I would be open to suggestions.

Also, if there is a good tutorial to point me to that would be great. I can't really find anything but samples. I have learned everything from the samples, but sections, paragraph, etc is all new to me and I would like to get a better understanding of what I've done.

[image]
[image]

```
public static Document CreateWorkOrderPDF2(Document document, string filename, string WorkOrderHeader, string myMessage)
    {
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;

        section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 40;
        //Sets the height of the top margin
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 100;
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 40;
        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 40;

        //MARGIN
        HeaderFooter header = section.Headers.Primary;
        header.Format.Font.Size = 16;
        header.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;

        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image headerImage = header.AddImage("../../Fonts/castorgate.regular.png");
        headerImage.Width = "2cm";

        Paragraph headerParagraph = section.AddParagraph();
        headerParagraph = header.AddParagraph(WorkOrderHeader);

        //BODY PARAGRAPH
        Paragraph bodyParagraph = section.AddParagraph();
        bodyParagraph = section.AddParagraph(myMessage);
        bodyParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 10;
        bodyParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkRed;


        //paragraph.Format.Distancne = "3cm";
        Paragraph renderDate = section.AddParagraph();
        renderDate = section.AddParagraph("Work Order Generated: ");
        renderDate.AddDateField();

        return document;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Paragraph bodyParagraph = section.AddParagraph();` adds an empty paragraph. I assume that is the extra space on the first page.
Same issue with `renderDate` in the following code block.
Just remove the calls `section.AddParagraph()` to remove the empty paragraphs if you don't want them.

MigraDoc is much like Word and understanding sections, paragraphs, &c. in Word will also help you with MigraDoc. That knowledge along with the samples and IntelliSense should get you going.

You can use MigraDoc to create an RTF file, open the RTF in Word, and click the pilcrow to show formatting characters in Word.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Thanks for the tip on the RTF. That should help me understand what is going on...